# XXE: Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference With XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, veracode, xxe

So I am running into an issue when I run a security scan on my application. [It turns out that I am failing to protect against XXE](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/611.html).
Here is a short snippet showing the offending code:

```
static void Main()
        {
            string inp = Console.ReadLine();
            string xmlStr = ""; //This has a value that is much too long to put into a single post

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp))
            {
                xmlStr = inp;
            }
            XmlDocument xmlDocObj = new XmlDocument {XmlResolver = null};
            xmlDocObj.LoadXml(xmlStr);
            XmlNodeList measureXmlNodeListObj = xmlDocObj.SelectNodes("REQ/MS/M");

            foreach (XmlNode measureXmlNodeObj in measureXmlNodeListObj)
            {
                XmlNode detailXmlNodeListObj = xmlDocObj.SelectSingleNode("REQ/DTD");
                string measureKey = measureXmlNodeObj.Attributes["KY"].Value;
                if (detailXmlNodeListObj.Attributes["MKY"].Value ==
                    measureKey) //Checking if selected MeasureKey is same 
                {
                    XmlNode filerNode = measureXmlNodeObj.SelectSingleNode("FS");

                    if (filerNode != null)
                    {

                        XDocument fixedFilterXmlObj = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(filerNode.OuterXml));

                        var measureFixedFilters = (from m in fixedFilterXmlObj.Element("FS").Elements("F")
                            select m).ToList();
                        foreach (var fixedFilter in measureFixedFilters)
                        {
                            var fixedFilterValues = (from m in fixedFilter.Elements("VS").Elements("V")
                                select m.Attribute("DESC").Value).ToList();

                            foreach (var value in fixedFilterValues)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(value.Trim());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

According to Veracode, the line that unsafe is `XDocument fixedFilterXmlObj = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(filerNode.OuterXml));`

But it seems like according to Owsap, [it should be safe](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#.NET):

> Both the XElement and XDocument objects in the System.Xml.Linq library
>   are safe from XXE injection by default. XElement parses only the
>   elements within the XML file, so DTDs are ignored altogether.
>   XDocument has DTDs disabled by default, and is only unsafe if
>   constructed with a different unsafe XML parser.

So it seems like I am making the mistake of using an usafe XML Parser, opening `XDocument` to XXE.

[I found a unit test that replicates the issue](https://github.com/deanf1/dotnet-security-unit-tests/blob/7e79679c619c0929b7c0b911428d238eafc2856d/DotNetUnitTests/results.aspx.cs#L100) and also has a safe usage of `XDocument` but I can't seem to find what exactly my code is unsafe, because I do not use:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;   // unsafe!
```

You can run my code to replicate the issue, but you should replace the line with the empty xmlStr with this value: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/w0YbLWEp) (too large for a single post)

Comment: I hope for a way to fix this problem in the context of SOAP endpoint handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how or why this works, but it does:

```
XDocument fixedFilterXmlObj;
using (XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(filerNode))
{
    nodeReader.MoveToContent();
    fixedFilterXmlObj = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
}
```